# What is special about /dev/tty?

Tags: unix

`ls -la /dev/tty` shows the output:

```
crw-rw-rw- 1 root tty 5, 0 Dec 14 22:21 /dev/tty
```

What does c at the beginning mean? When I do something like `pwd > /dev/tty` it prints to the stdout. What does the file /dev/tty contain?

Answer (score 136, accepted):

The 'c' means it's a character device. tty is a special file representing the 'controlling terminal' for the current process.

**Character Devices**

Unix supports 'device files', which aren't really files at all, but file-like access points to hardware devices.
A 'character' device is one which is interfaced byte-by-byte (as opposed to buffered IO).

**TTY**

/dev/tty is a special file, representing the terminal for the current process. So, when you `echo 1 > /dev/tty`, your message ('1') will appear on your screen. Likewise, when you `cat /dev/tty`, your subsequent input gets duplicated (until you press Ctrl-C).

`/dev/tty` doesn't 'contain' anything as such, but you can read from it and write to it (for what it's worth). I can't think of a good use for it, but there are similar files which are very useful for simple IO operations (e.g. `/dev/ttyS0` is normally your serial port)

This quote is from http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Text-Terminal-HOWTO-7.html#ss7.3 :

> /dev/tty stands for the controlling terminal (if any) for the current
>   process.  To find out which tty's are attached to which processes use
>   the "ps -a" command at the shell prompt (command line). Look at the
>   "tty" column. For the shell process you're in, /dev/tty is the
>   terminal you are now using. Type "tty" at the shell prompt to see what
>   it is (see manual pg. tty(1)). /dev/tty is something like a link to
>   the actually terminal device name with some additional features for
>   C-programmers: see the manual page tty(4).

Here is the man page: http://linux.die.net/man/4/tty

Comment: One good use for `/dev/tty` is if you're trying to call an editor in a pipeline (e.g., with `xargs`). Since the standard input of `xargs` is some list of files rather than your terminal, just doing, e.g., `| xargs emacs` will screw up your terminal. Instead you can use `| xargs sh -c 'emacs "$@" </dev/tty' emacs` to connect the editor to your terminal even though the input of `xargs` is coming from elsewhere. (The `xargs` man page on my system suggests this usage.)

Answer (score 16):

`/dev/tty` is a synonym for the controlling terminal (if any) of the current process.  As jtl999 says, it's a character special file; that's what the `c` in the `ls -l` output means.

`man 4 tty` or `man -s 4 tty` should give you more information, or you can read the man page online [here](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man4/tty.4.html).

Incidentally, `pwd > /dev/tty` doesn't *necessarily* print to the shell's stdout (though it is the `pwd` command's standard output).  If the shell's standard output has been redirected to something other than the terminal, `/dev/tty` still refers to the terminal.

You can also read from `/dev/tty`, which will normally read from the keyboard.

Comment: I can't understand your `pwd > /dev/tty doesn't necessarily print to stdout. If standard output has been redirected to something other than the terminal`. In my opinion, it will always set file descriptor 1 of the process to /dev/tty. Could you explain?

Comment: @dagang: Your opinion is mistaken. If standard output is redirected to a file, file descriptor 1 will refer to that file, *not* to the terminal. That's what redirection means.

Comment: Yes, fd 1 can refer to any file, but `>/dev/tty` always means make fd 1 refer to the terminal, regardless of where fd 1 was referring to. Could you provide an example to support your argument?

Comment: @dagang: Ah, I see where the confusion comes from. Yes, `pwd` always prints to `stdout`, and yes, in this case `stdout` goes to `/dev/tty`. My point was that that's not necessarily the standard output *of the shell*. (Though the fact that `pwd` is necessarily a shell builtin probably complicates things.)

Comment: An example of how it makes a difference: `( echo to stdout ; echo to tty > /dev/tty ) > a_file`  One will find "to stdout" to be redirected to a_file, but "to tty" will still appear on the terminal the shell is running from and not be redirected to a_file.  The sub-shell running the part inside the `( ... )` has stdout redirected to a file but the controlling terminal the still whatever terminal the parent shell is running in, e.g.. your xterm or ssh or serial console, etc.

Comment: I found it very useful to do something like this `find . -type d -name dummy | tee /dev/tty | xargs rm`

Comment: Rereading this a few years later, my statement that "`pwd` is necessarily a shell builtin" was incorrect. It *can* be a shell builtin, but it doesn't have to be. I was probably thinking of `cd`.

Answer (score 4):

The 'c' means it's a character special file.