# Pausing and restarting terminal output

Tags: c, io, terminal, sleep, backspace

What I'm trying to do is have the terminal print out a string, pause, and then write over that string. What's happening though is that the program simply prints out the final result, without ever showing the first string.

I thought I could use `sleep` to do this, but it doesn't work. Why not?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void){

    char message[] = "Hello there";
    int messageLength = sizeof(message);
    int i;

    printf("Hello, Dave.");
    sleep(2);
    for(i = 0; i < messageLength; i++)
        printf("\b");
    printf("Anyone there?\n");

    return 0;

}
```

**Updated version, thanks to answers:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>

void twprint(char* output, int outputLength, struct timespec* delay);
void twbackspace(int length, struct timespec* delay);

int main(void){

    char message1[] = "Hello, Dave.";
    char message2[] = "Are you there, Dave?";
    char message3[] = "I heard you talking in the pod.";
    char message4[] = "Dave?";
    struct timespec duration = { .tv_sec = 0, .tv_nsec = (100 * 1000 * 1000) }; 
    /* ^ .tv_nsec = one hundred million nanoseconds */

    twprint(message1, sizeof(message1)/sizeof(char), &duration);
    sleep(2);
    twbackspace(sizeof(message1)/sizeof(char), &duration);

    twprint(message2, sizeof(message2)/sizeof(char), &duration);
    sleep(2);
    twbackspace(sizeof(message2)/sizeof(char), &duration);

    twprint(message3, sizeof(message3)/sizeof(char), &duration);
    sleep(2);
    twbackspace(sizeof(message3)/sizeof(char), &duration);

    sleep(2);
    duration.tv_nsec *= 5;
    twprint(message4, sizeof(message4)/sizeof(char), &duration);

    printf("\n");

    return 0;

}

void twprint(char* output, int outputLength, struct timespec* delay){

    int i;
    struct timespec remaining; /* dummy parameter */

    for(i = 0; i < outputLength; i++){
        printf("%c", output[i]);
        fflush(stdout);
        nanosleep(delay, &remaining);
    }

}

void twbackspace(int length, struct timespec* delay){

    int i;
    struct timespec remaining; /* dummy parameter */

    for(i = 0; i < length; i++){
        printf("\b \b");
        fflush(stdout);
        nanosleep(delay, &remaining);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are erasing your message in the for loop, thats why.

Comment: @valter, you don't say? :D

Comment: @valter That's why what? Did you even read what the OP wants to do?

Comment: @JimBalter He gave me a good laugh though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output of printf is buffered and won't be printed to the console until the buffer is full, you print a newline, or call fflush(stdout). Try:

```
...
printf("Hello, Dave.");
fflush(stdout);
sleep(2);
...
```

Wikipedia provides [a good explanation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams) of standard streams and their behavior with respect to buffering.

Answer (score 1):

You need to flush the output stream to get the line to show up:

```
printf("Hello, Dave.");
fflush(stdout);
```

Normally, console output would go to `stderr`, by the way. If you did that, you wouldn't have to worry about flushing (on many platforms) because `stderr` is typically unbuffered (so output is immediate), whereas `stdout` is typically line-buffered (so output doesn't show up until you write a newline character).

Comment: @AmadeusDrZaius stderr is, as the name suggests, for error output; I would consider it a mistake to write anything other than diagnostics to it. It defaults to unbuffered to assure that error output is seen immediately (and even if the program crashes). However, both stdout and stderr can be redirected to a device or file instead of to the terminal, and they can have their buffering changed (see http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setbuf.3.html). For output that absolutely must go to the terminal, you can use /dev/tty (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8514735/what-is-special-about-dev-tty)