# Count only visible files in directory

Tags: linux, bash

I'm having problem with hidden file in my directory. If I use `$(find . -type f | wc -l)` it shows 8 files, which counts hidden file too, there should be only 7 files.

Is there anything that could count only visible files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignore the names that start with `.` by saying:

```
find . ! -name '.*' -type f | wc -l
```

From the `man` page:

> ! expression
>
> ```
>  -not expression
>          This is the unary NOT operator.  It evaluates to true if the
>          expression is false.
> ```

If you have filenames with newlines, then you can do using `gnu find` (as suggested by [gniourf gniourf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1815797/gniourf-gniourf) in comments):

```
find . ! -name '.*' -type f -maxdepth 1 -printf 'x' | wc -c
```

Comment: This will fail if there are filenames containing newlines. Might as well add a `-printf 'x'` to only output a character instead of a filename and count with `wc -c`.

Comment: To count symlinks, just do `find . -follow ! -name '.*' -type f | wc -l`

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -type f -not -path '*/\.*' | wc -l
```

`-not -path` allows you to ignore files with name starting with `.` (hidden files)

Answer (score 0):

Exclude all files starting with ( . )

```
find ./  ! -name '\.*' -type f | wc -l

! simply negates the search
```

If that doesnt work then try this dirty looking solution:

```
ls -lR | egrep '^(-|l|c|b|p|P|D|C|M|n|s)'  | wc -l
```

Listed all types of files there excluding directories.
You can find the type of files in linux [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23235991/whats-the-meaning-of-c-in-result-of-command-ls-l-dev-tty/23236026#23236026)

without `-R` of you want to look only in same dir.

Comment: i tried your dirty solution :P but i get 12 files but there should be only 9 :) http://i.imgur.com/iVN372Y.png --> this is the structure of directory

Comment: just added something to answr please try now

Comment: Thats because its not including your link file, I am sorry for this trial and error. Please check the solution now.

Comment: how about accepting it as an answer to indicate what worked to people  visiting this page?