# How can I from stdin even when called in a pipe

Tags: bash

How can I define a function `bar` in a Bash script such that `echo foo | bar` in that script will read an input from the script's stdin and not the pipe? In other words, if `bar` is:

```
function bar(){
  read ZOO
}
```

I want it to wait for my input rather than setting `ZOO` to `"foo"`

Comment: A pipe closes `stdin` and replaces it with `stdout` of a previously chained command. You would have to manually replace it yourself after reading the pipe. What are you trying to do exactly? Does `echo foo && bar` work?

Comment: The only reason to call `bar` in that fashion would be to assign the string `foo` to `ZOO`. I think you need a more complex example to demonstrate what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea of a pipe is to connect *stdout* of the process on the left side of the pipe with *stdin* of the process on the right side of the pipe. So `foo` is in this case piped into stdin of the function `bar()`.

If you want to read explicitly from the current *terminal*, then pass [the special device `/dev/tty`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8514735/171318)  to stdin of `read`:

```
function bar() {
    read ZOO < /dev/tty
}
```

Comment: The question doesn't say something about that. Imo that does not belong here.