# How to force input from terminal even if executable's input is redirected from a file?

Tags: c++, linux, input, io-redirection

I want to debug a code which has a huge input which is redirected from a file using

```
./a.out < input.in
```

but I wish to read an enter line from keyboard within a program at some point.
Like the following program should not run beyond input() until an enter is read from keyboard but cin should input from file.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
   int a;
   cin>>a;
   input();
}
```

Comment: In short: You cannot. Why arent you running your program in the debugger, and set a breakpoint just on `input();`?

Comment: My editor doesn't support that feature ..

Comment: Just use `gdb` from the command line then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a solution if you are under a unix like system. You can usually open your terminal as a new file handle. On my system the name of this file is `/dev/tty`. 
See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8514853/657700 for more inforamtion.

Here is an example program that reads from its standard input and also ask the user to enter a line interactively:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // open our terminal
    std::ifstream term("/dev/tty");

    // read 10 lines from input
    vector<string> lines(10);
    for(auto& l : lines)
        getline(std::cin, l);

    // read a line from tty
    string tty_line;
    cout << "Please enter a line:\n";
    cout << "--------------------\n";
    getline(term, tty_line);

    cout << endl;
    // output 5 lines from input
    cout << "First 5 lines read from stdin:\n";
    cout << "------------------------------\n";
    for(int i=0; i<5; ++i)
        cout << lines.at(i) << '\n';
    // output the line read from tty
    cout << "Line read from tty:\n";
    cout << "-------------------\n";
    cout << tty_line << '\n';
    // output the 5 remaining lines read from input
    cout << "Last 5 lines read from stdin:\n";
    cout << "-----------------------------\n";
    for(int i=5; i<10; ++i)
        cout << lines.at(i) << '\n';
}
```

Here is my session using this program:

```
fjardon@redacted 12:00:28 ~/tmp
$ seq 10 | ./read-stdin-terminal.exe
Please enter a line:
--------------------
something

First 5 lines read from stdin:
------------------------------
1
2
3
4
5
Line read from tty:
-------------------
something
Last 5 lines read from stdin:
-----------------------------
6
7
8
9
10
```