# Missing a prompt of read command when using pipe in Bash?

Tags: bash, pipe

I have a file named: "`./script`" which contain "`read -p 'Input Your Name:' name`"***(1)***

When i open my terminal then type `bash ./script`. It show a prompt. But it show nothing when i type `cat ./script | bash`***(2)***.

Are there any commands to read that file and achieve the same result of ***(1)***. Please help me. Thank in advance.

**This is my first question. Please improve this if needed.**

[Steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0cGe.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The manual says:

> **-p prompt**
>
> Display prompt on standard error, without a trailing newline, before attempting to read any input. **The prompt is displayed only if input is coming from a terminal.**

When you do `cat ./script | bash`, the input is coming from a pipe, not a terminal. A workaround is reading from [`/dev/tty`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8514735/what-is-special-about-dev-tty), e.g:

```
read -p 'Input Your Name:' name </dev/tty
```

Comment: This will also solve the problem of `read` consuming a line of the script, since `read` was reading from the same file handle as `bash` itself.